# Google OAuth2 - How to save the user's effort to enter the username and password again?

Tags: iphone, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have read the flow of Google OAuth2 flow, but I don't know how to or what to store permanently so that next time or in the future, user doesn't need to input username or password in my app again.

---

Here is my understanding:

1. Assuming the user just launched my app for the first time.
2. I produce a UIWebView in my app and load it with the Google OAuth2 request url (with all necessary parameters).
3. Google will then return me the login page and I display it in the UIWebView.
4. User input the username and password and tap "sign in"
5. Google will return the consent page in the UIWebView and ask user's approval.
6. User tap "permit"
7. Google will then return the "code" as the title of the returning page.
8. I get the "code", then ask for "token" for the following steps (Google Reader API calling, etc)

---

Ok, I understand the above steps. But they are for the first time usage, right?

- What then if the user launches my app for the 2nd and following
  times?
- Should I store the "code" value in my app and if the user gets in my
  app again, I just begin from step 7?
- What I should do to avoid the user to input their username and
  password again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will receive back the access token and the refresh token. Those are the only things you need to store. The access token will be used to make the calls to the Google APIs. The refresh token will be used to get a new access token after the old one expires.